# id missing on join table ,have no value from id

Tags: php, sql, join

Got next:

SQL:

```
LEFT JOIN `me_pictures` ON me_events.id = me_pictures.eventid
```

PHP:

```
$id = ($row['id']);
```

`$id` doesn't always return a value, but I need them.
sample : Id 12 is present in table `me_events` but not in table `me_pictures`,
so I do not always have a value from `id`.

Is a solution for this?

Comment: You have to be more descriptive than that.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks for comment , i got LEFT join but also not working

Comment: Are you selecting me_events.id ?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, that's just a half SQL statement.

Comment: i hope this make at more clearly [link]http://www.u-site.nl [/link]